# Can I use normal http and https for the same endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, https

So I have a client who is going to upgrade to ssl, but they currently use just plain http.

I want to change the endpoint for the service.  To use https.

```
    <binding name="basicHttpSSLBinding" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00">
          <security mode="Transport" > 
          </security>
        </binding>
```

The question is will their connection to the web service using http still work until they change the address to https?  Do I need two endpoints to pull this off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer is no, when you switch to HTTPS then HTTP won't work any longer. Yes, you'll need two endpoint: one with security mode transport and one with security mode none. They'll also need different address attribute values.